# What is the easy way to render a 2D cadastral plan in 3D?

Tags: 3d, sketchup

Is there an easy way to render a plan like this :
[Cadastral plan exemple](https://www.google.com/search?q=cadastral%20plan&client=ms-android-samsung&prmd=inmv&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ7aRcgZgyJaNYjco5ZPRiv3e_WUA:1581180002599&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWzYXDssLnAhXSxYUKHQNlCNYQ_AUoAXoECA4QAQ&biw=360&bih=560&dpr=4#imgrc=nu8Bol9zSvCLzM)

In simple 3D, just to show the shadows ? With Sketchup for example ?

Like an automatic image trace, where I define the elevation in a second time.
Or do I have to sketch everything...

Comment: Depends on what kind of format your plan is in. If it is a proper plan in a GIS file then no problem just load the 3d elevation data for that area and map data on that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not have an all-in-one geographic data system that can show also the wanted 3D view.

In 3D CAD or artistic design programs, one can map planar images onto surfaces. Your case needs a straight vertical projection which is not the same as the usual surface texture mapping called UV-mapping by 3D designers. Artists expect something which mathematicians call conformity. You expect the planar map lands on the original plane map coordinates. An example of an entry-level CAD program:

[image]

Here's a fake terrain model made by lofting together some imaginary elevation curves and adding some thickness. Above it levitates a fake planar map. It's actually a drawing in the same CAD program because this is a free version of a CAD program and many pro features like importing vector drawings are disabled.

The mapping you expect(=to project the planar drawing straight vertically on the surface) is done here:

[image]

When the result is watched straight on the face, the vertically projected plane map still looks original. UV mapping in the normal way keeps local distortions minimized, but in the straight, on-the-face view the result is distorted. Comparison:

[image]

On the left, the map is projected vertically.

On the right, the map (=a bitmap copy of it) is stretched over the surface like artists want it to happen, with minimal local distortions. It's useless as a map. (sorry for the color difference, UV mapping works only with bitmap images in this program, but it's automatic)

**Now you can have an idea**: Why not simply layer in a photo editor or in a drawing program a top view of a rendered terrain model and the map? With properly selected layer blending mode and colors both the shading of the model and the map can be readable. With a simple map, they are visible like in the previous image.

The rendering in this program is algorithmic, it doesn't present daylight at any time of the day and of the year. One cannot guess the right 3D form from the top projection. Rendering here only helps the recognition. To see the form properly one must have a 3D model which can be rotated, panned, and zoomed. An alternative is to have a true 3D stereo view with 3D glasses.

Distribution as 3D is possible as a 3D PDF which can be watched with Adobe Reader. Rotating, zooming and panning are free. Please refer to Adobe's documentation for details or make your own tests.

I have also tested rendering in Photoshop's 3D where one can set properly a directed light. One has the same in SketchUp. The latter has even the possibility to set the light by day and time. Unfortunately, the 3D form is still not properly decidable from a single projection, a true 3D stereo view or free rotatability is a must. See an example in Photoshop:

[image]

Here the distant light comes from the southern sky. The terrain model is not the same as in previous images. Can you see the forms right? I cannot. Right recognition is possible from this image only if one already knows what is a plain, what is a hill and what is a valley. He can match this image with the existing terrain knowledge, but deciding the unknown terrain forms from this is pure guessing.

In addition, deep shadows render the black map drawing unreadable but that can easily be fixed with blending modes, and colors or by inserting a shadow to the lines and texts, for ex a white shadow on too-dark areas.

A special rendering could fix the ambiguity, but that's not based on real light. Many 3D texturing systems have a bump map where the grey shade presents the elevation. Seeing how dark a place on the terrain is tells the elevation. Can someone read it intuitively so that he sees the 3D form - that's a different problem. I guess some training is a must.

Another special rendering is already used in maps. It's based on imaginary light:

[image]

The steepness of terrain features is presented with brightness. Everything has a sunny side and the dark side. On the sunny side, a steeper slope is brighter. On the dark side, a steeper slope is darker. In the example the sunny side is northwest. To avoid bad discontinuities the direction threshold between the dark side and the sunny side is fuzzy. I have no idea which software is programmed to generate this.

The 3D CAD program I used at the beginning of this answer is DesignSpark Mechanical, a limited, but free version of SpaceClaim. I cannot, unfortunately, give a list of programs that can cover this task without obstacles. I guess you want to select freely the vertically projected map a new vector drawing, a bitmap image, or even a PDF without any attempts to explode it in Illustrator or Inkscape into parts.

The surface must be possible to define at least as a mesh that is generated from a list of elevation points+smoothed to a wanted degree in selected areas. Existing surfaces must be able to be imported and the ability to loft together elevation profile curves or elevation contours(shifted at first to right elevations) is a plus.

I guess a monster named Blender covers all this, but it's a guess.

At least Rhinoceros and its low-cost cousin Moi3D can project Ai vector drawings. A vector image + text in a PDF can be extracted for it in Illustrator.

**A SketchUp user forum has at least one discussion of your problem**. See the case: [Projecting a site design plan onto terrain created from contours](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/projecting-a-site-design-plan-onto-terrain-created-from-contours/65988). One of the provided answers seem to tell a recipe for successful parallel projection instead of stretching in an artistic way. I haven't tested it.